# Calling function multiple times or storing returned value, Performance wise

Tags: php, performance

In many WordPress Themes and Frameworks I found these lines of code:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js lt-ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
```

I noticed the multiple calls for `language_attributes()` which I think is unnecessary time spent even for a simple function like this one, so I used this code:

```
<?php ob_start(); language_attributes(); $language_attributes = ob_get_clean(); ?>

<!--[if lt IE 7]><html <?php echo $language_attributes; ?> class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html <?php echo $language_attributes; ?> class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html <?php echo $language_attributes; ?> class="no-js lt-ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html <?php echo $language_attributes; ?> class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->

<?php unset($language_attributes); ?>
```

to avoid calling `language_attributes()` multiple times, but the more I see the use of the first pattern the more I doubt my decision so I decided to ask for an expert opinion.

So, here's my questions:

in a broader aspect - not limited to this specific function - if the function do the exact every time

***What's the benefit of calling a function multiple times over storing the returned value?***

Like, is there some hidden caching mechanism in `php` that do run-time caching of a function call so this way i don't need to store the returned value.

Comment: wordress is not exactly known for *performance*

Comment: Performance wise you should profile the website and fix the stuff that is causing problems. You should not fixate on stuff like this, unless you have a good reason to (i.e. if you know that it is slow).

Comment: if you were writing your own you would never do this but if you want tot be uber flexible and accommodate all the ad dons, templateing  et al sometimes this is going to happen, its one of the trade-offs in life

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I'm not talking about a website performance, i'm talking about a programmer coding conventions, multiple function calls or storing the returned value?

Comment: @Bonga Then remove "Performance wise" from the title.

Comment: @Dagon I can't get what you are saying

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen It's about performance **** IS THERE A PERFORMANCE BENEFIT OF CALLING A FUNCTION MULTIPLE TIMES OVER STORING THE RETURNED VALUE

Comment: @Bonga In most cases storing the returned value is better for performance. Defiantly if the functions takes a good amount of computation.

Comment: There is no performance benefit on such a simple function, if you have a complex fucntion, than you can cache results , and there are Cache classes that can do that , basically difference in your example is 0.000001ms or so. And you are using s bit more memory ;)

Comment: if you don't like wordpress, stop using it, your never going to get anywhere rewriting bits of it to your  preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question as directly as I can, it depends. Does the function do the exact same thing each time, with a performance cost? Is the function cached / returning an easily calculable value without touching storage? Will it be opcached or otherwise runtime-cached? All of these affect your decisions about the call.

Beyond that there are even more questions to ask. Why are you concerned with this call? Have you measured its impact? Have you measured higher grains? Other parts of the stack? There are likely tons of optimizations that would be more effective, assuming you have not measured anything.

With all that said, there is a good chance this is premature optimization, not something you should consider yourself with. I recommend [The Mature Optimization Handbook](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/the-mature-optimization-handbook/10151784131623920), which covers this topic extensively, and should help you on your path.

Comment: OK let me start by saying that this specific call is not my only concern, what i mean is: if the function do the exact every time is  there some hidden caching mechanism in `php` that do run-time caching of a function call so this way i don't need to store the returned value?

Comment: Thank you, for this book reference it actually seems it may help me a lot, your answer is by far the only one that touched what I was asking for, I don't know who voted you down and for what, I wished that you may have some specific knowledge about `php` runtime caching for function calls, it would be of great help, thank you agin

Comment: @Bonga: Well before you edited your question it appeared you were looking for `get_language_attributes()`.  Your new edit added "in a broader aspect", "hidden caching mechanism".

Comment: @AbraCadaver Sorry for that, I forget how programmers are easily distracted, I was asking the balded question while i remembered that I was annoyed by not having a WordPress `get_` style function to only return `language_attributes`, my bad

Comment: @Bonga yes, there is a caching mechanism for runtime that catches opcodes/bytecode called [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php), or [Opcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php). It's usually loaded into your web server (Apache, Nginx, the built-in server). Please read [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_accelerator) and Google around for opcache, that should help!

Answer (score 1):

Without following the convoluted Wordpress code chain (I hate Wordpress) there is no way to know.  The actual invocation of the function obviously adds time, though it is probably negligible, but this function call executes at least two other function calls in this case.

If any of the functions are doing anything substantial (database query, including files, looping, extensive regex, etc.) then this could compound into performance problems.

In general best practice, especially if you don't know what all of the functions are doing, it would be best to call it once.  Unless of course there is the possibility of the return / result changing across calls and you need the differing information.

You can do it using:

```
$language_attributes = get_bloginfo('language');
```

Or how that works:

```
$language_attributes = str_replace('_', '-', get_locale());
```

[Function Reference/get bloginfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo)

Comment: actually the `language_attributes` function do more than that, and there's also the applied filters from plugins